# How to filter elements within a list and generate frequency table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ["Hi how","I am fine","Ila say Hi"],
                   'tokens':[['Hi','how'],['I','am','fine'],['Ila','say','Hi']],
                    'labels':[['A','B'],['C','B','A'],['D','B','A']]})
```

I would like to do two things

a) count of each labels

b) count tokens under each label

I was trying something like below

```
flattened = [] 
op = itertools.zip_longest(df['tokens'],df['labels'])
for i in op:
    for la in df['labels']: 
        if la == 'A' : 
        flattened.append(val)
```

But this is incorrect and going no-where

I expect my output to have two dataframes/tables like as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `value_counts` after flattening the columns `tokens` and `labels` using `hstack`

```
t = np.hstack(df['tokens'])
l = np.hstack(df['labels'])
```

Count of each label

```
pd.value_counts(l)

B    3
A    3
D    1
C    1
dtype: int64
```

Count tokens under each label

```
pd.DataFrame(zip(l, t)).value_counts()

0  1   
A  Hi      2
   fine    1
B  am      1
   how     1
   say     1
C  I       1
D  Ila     1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Pandas's `explode` method:

```
>>> df2 = df[['labels', 'tokens']].apply(pd.Series.explode)
>>> df2.labels.value_counts()

B    3
A    3
D    1
C    1
Name: labels, dtype: int64

>>> df2[['labels', 'tokens']].value_counts()
labels  tokens
A       Hi        2
        fine      1
B       am        1
        how       1
        say       1
C       I         1
D       Ila       1
dtype: int64
```